# NullValues Option Not Working When Loading to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

When reading a CSV into a DataTable, I am trying to add options for boolean and null values that don't seem to be working. For example, a file containing data similar to:

```
Id,MaxDiscount,Name,Active,AltId
1,,Foo,1,ABC123
2,10,Bar,0,DEF345
```

And the following logic that uses a schema file to dynamically get the headers and data types we are expecting:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = false;
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<int>().NullValues.Add(string.Empty);
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanFalseValues.Add("0");
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanTrueValues.Add("1");

    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {
        foreach (var p in schema.Properties)
        {
            var type = Type.GetType(p.Type, true, true);
            var dc = new DataColumn
            {
                ColumnName = p.Name,
                Unique = p.IsId,
                AllowDBNull = p.Nullable,
                DataType = type
            };

            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        }
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

This leads to the error `String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. Couldn't store <0> in Active Column.  Expected type is Boolean.`

If I manually change the data and replace `0` with `false` and `1` with `true`, I then the boolean values work, but I get a similar error: `Input string was not in a correct format. Couldn't store <> in MaxDiscount Column.  Expected type is Int32.`

Is there something I am missing here in order to get this to work? Or do the Type Converter options only work on known objects?

EDIT:

I am unable to use any pre-defined object models when parsing the CSV files as they can contain any number of fields. As long as a schema exists, then the program should know how to handle it. An example schema would be something like the following:

```
{
  "type": "Part",
  "bucket": "s3Bucket",
  "prefix": "prefix/of/datafile",
  "targetDirectory": "..\\path\\to\\working\\dir",
  "delimiter": ",",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "Id",
      "type": "System.String",
      "required": true,
      "nullable": false,
      "isId": true,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "minLength": 6,
      "maxLength": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "MaxDiscount",
      "type": "System.Int32",
      "required": true,
      "nullable": true,
      "isId": false,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "minLength": -1,
      "maxLength": -1
    },
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "System.String",
      "required": true,
      "nullable": false,
      "isId": false,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 127
    },
    {
      "name": "Active",
      "type": "System.Boolean",
      "required": true,
      "nullable": false,
      "isId": false,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "AltId",
      "type": "System.String",
      "required": true,
      "nullable": true,
      "isId": false,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 127
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, the `Properties` in the schema would relate to columns in the CSV file. This, in theory, would allow me to parse the files and validate the data types at runtime, rather than having to create a new object model each time a new CSV layout is introduced.

Comment: where / how is `schema` defined?

Comment: What happens if you use the nullable int version `GetOptions<int?>()` instead of the non-nullable one?

Comment: @grek40 schema is parsed from a JSON file that contains information about the CSV being read. When I use the nullable int option I get the exact same error

Comment: Can you post your schema information?

Comment: @WaelAbbas Schema info has been posted, thank you!

Comment: @DrydenLong  check my answern and If you need datatable as data source only you can replace it with `List<csvData>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion the `CsvDataReader` class is useless - the implementation of `GetFieldType` returns `typeof(string)`, `GetValue` also returns `string`s, so although it implements the typed data accessor methods, they are never called by the `DataTable` class `Load` method.

Thus no `CsvHelper` mapping occurs - the conversion is done by `DataTable` using standard string to type converters.

I would suggest removing the usage of `CsvDataReader` class and replacing the `dt.Load(dr);` call with something like this:

```
static void Load(DataTable dt, CsvReader csv)
{
    if (csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord)
    {
        if (!csv.Read()) return;
        csv.ReadHeader();
    }
    var valueTypes = new Type[dt.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < valueTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        var dc = dt.Columns[i];
        var type = dc.DataType;
        if (dc.AllowDBNull && type.IsValueType)
            type = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        valueTypes[i] = type;
    }
    var valueBuffer = new object[valueTypes.Length];
    dt.BeginLoadData();
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < valueBuffer.Length; i++)
            valueBuffer[i] = csv.GetField(valueTypes[i], i);
        dt.LoadDataRow(valueBuffer, true);
    }
    dt.EndLoadData();
}
```

Essentially preparing column type mapping and using `CsvReader.GetField(type, index)` method for populating the `DataRow` values. This way the conversion is performed by the `CsvReader` class and will use all the conversion options.

Btw, none of the shown options for boolean or null values is really needed - all they are handled by the `CsvHelper` default type converters.

Comment: This perfect, a little more complicated than I hoped (it always is) but exactly the results I needed.

Comment: I just lost 2 hours and skipped lunch because CsvDataReader ignores CsvReader's configuration ....

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :(

Answer (score 1):

From [CsvHelper documentation](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/data-table)

> If you want to specify columns and column types, the data table will be loaded with the types **automatically** converted.

What i see its ignoring `CsvReader` type converter options when using `CsvDataReader`.

But if you use `csv.GetRecords` it will use defined type converter options.

```
List<csvData> result = csv.GetRecords<csvData>().ToList();
```

You will need to have as class for your csv file as below

```
public class csvData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MaxDiscount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string AltId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Second try]**

I was able to load data into `DataTable` object via `CsvDataReader` as long as the collection of `DataColumns` was created by `CsvDataReader` and `Configuration.Delimiter` was set to comma, but... boolean field (`Active`) wasn't really boolean.

As per my tests and my understanding of documentation, there is only one way to get proper data - via helper class, which needs to set [attributes](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/) to fields. Two of them are very important:

> `BooleanFalseValuesAttribute` The string values used to represent a
>   boolean false when converting.
>   `BooleanTrueValuesAttribute` The string values used to represent a boolean true when converting.

So, the decoration of class may look like:

```
public class MyData
{
    [Name("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Name("MaxDiscount")]
    public int? MaxDiscount { get; set; }
    [Name("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Name("Active")]
    [BooleanTrueValues("1")]
    [BooleanFalseValues("0")]
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    [Name("AltId")]
    public string AltId { get; set; }
}
```

And helper class, which maps fields:

```
public class MyDataMapper: ClassMap<MyData>
{
    public MyDataMapper()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.MaxDiscount);
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.Active);
        Map(m => m.AltId);
    }
}
```

Then i've tried to set configuration:

```
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyDataMapper>();
```

to be able to grab data into `DataTable` via `CsvDataReader` object, but... no success :(

Seems that `CsvDataReader` ignores configuration for some reason (or i wasn't able to successfully set it up).

Whenever there's a need to map fields, the documentation says that the correct way to grab data is to use `GetRecords<T>` method:

```
var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
```

See: [Mapping properties](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-properties/)

If i understand you well, you want to fetch data into DataTable object...  Take a look at this:

```
List<MyData> records = null;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(myfile))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = false;
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyDataMapper>();
    records = csv.GetRecords<MyData>().ToList();
    dt = records.Select(x=>dt.LoadDataRow(new object[]
            {
                x.Id,
                x.MaxDiscount,
                x.Name,
                x.Active,
                x.AltId
            },false))
            .CopyToDataTable();
     dt.Dump();
```

A result is:

```
Id MaxDiscount Name Active AltId
1  null        Foo  True   ABC123 
2  10          Bar  False  DEF345
```

Comment: to reproduce the issue you have to add datatable columns manually and give it data type like `Active` is boolean.

Comment: @WaelAbbas, thanks for your valuable comment. I've updated my answer. Please, take a look.

Comment: This answer is great, but I neglected to leave out an important detail and that is I cannot use pre-defined objects. The purpose of the app I am writing is to take in any CSV file and parse it into a datatable. I am in the process up updating my question accordingly

Comment: @DrydenLong, i think, it can't be done with `CsvDataReader`. Please, read github "forum" for reported issues: [GetValue of CsvDataReader doesnt support TypeConverter](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1227) and also Ivan Stoev answer.